# Why did not show toastr in my web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner in asp.net mvc and want to use toast notification to show any message to user,read [this](http://johnpapa.net/toastr100beta/) tutorial and write this code in my view page:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="مشاهده" onclick="behzad()">
```

and this java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function behzad() {
        //alert("ok");
        toastr.info('Hi Mahedee, This information for you.')

        toastr.success('Are you the six fingered man?', 'Inigo Montoya');

    }
</script>
```

but press the submit button i can see notification,how can i solve that problem?

and add this link to my view page:

```
<link href="~/Content/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/toastr.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to provide some more information here. What does it do? Does it give you an error in the console or does nothing all happen? Did you correctly include the scripts and css and can you show us how you did that?

Comment: @Kenneth i get this error in browser console:TypeError: $ is undefined
 toastr.js:391:17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Did You follow these steps ??**

bower install  toastr

Link to toastr.css

Link to toastr.js

toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?')

**I Created this plunkr check the order of the scripts that are being loaded and check you are doing the same .. Thank you**

`enter code here` http://plnkr.co/edit/CMkR8Ud7DOCnJCsGofvL?p=preview

Comment: please review my question,add that links but not solve my problem.

Comment: i get this error in browser console:TypeError: $ is undefined
 toastr.js:391:17

Comment: load jquery first then toastr.js

Answer (score 0):

toaster is using jQuery,
make sure you are importing jQuery **before** importing toaster